# Trying to count certain strings inside an excel report file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I've created this program which takes an excel file, reads, creates objects and inserts them into the database, I need to keep count of certain materials used in maintenance and I'm trying to count the times keywords like "battery" and "antenna" are said in the supplies used report. but my code only counts the word "Antena", anybody know why this is?

```
var suppliesquery = (from sm in db.TaskSuppliesUsed
                     where sm.suppliesUsed.ToString().ToLower().Contains("bateria")  ||
                           sm.suppliesUsed.ToString().ToLower().Contains("antena") ||
                           sm.suppliesUsed.ToString().ToLower().Contains("sim")     ||
                           sm.suppliesUsed.ToString().ToLower().Contains("simcard")
                     select sm).FirstOrDefault();

if (suppliesquery != null)
{
    int bateria = 0;
    int simcard = 0;
    int antena = 0;
    
    foreach (var s in suppliesquery.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        string[] insumos = suppliesquery.suppliesUsed.ToString().ToLower().Split(',');
        foreach (var i in insumos)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case "bateria":
                    bateria++;
                    break;

                case "sim":
                case "simcard":
                    simcard++;
                    break;

                case "antena plana":
                    antena++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the report, the supplies are normally formatted like this: "Antena Plana,Bateria,Cable" and so on.

*Can you explain what you expect `foreach (var s in suppliesquery.ToString().ToLower())` to do?* There's a column in the excel report that states the supplies used, I'm reading it via query with suppliesused.  [Screen shot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZmbt.png).

Comment: Can you explain what you expect `foreach (var s in suppliesquery.ToString().ToLower())` to do?

Comment: Click anywhere on the `string[] insumos` line. Press F9 so it goes red. Run the program til it stops with a yellow bar. Hover `suppliesUsed` then click  the magnifying glass in the tooltip. Take a screenshot of the Text Visualizer and add it to your question

Comment: When you do `foreach (var s in suppliesquery.ToString().ToLower())` you are iterating through the **individual characters in the string `suppliesquery.ToString()`**.  If you are trying to count the numbers of certain keywords in an excel column, this is almos certainly wrong.